# Preventing output from being overwritten using QGIS Model Designer)

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, model

I have built a (simple) Processing Model with the Qgis Modeler.
But **I can't figure out how I can prevent the output from being overwritten.**

In this case (see pic), my last process is "Add geometry attributes" and I am using an Expression for the Output. But when I run the process more than once, **it always overwrites the .shp-file it was exporting before.**

- A workaround was to add Date and Time stamps to the file-name.
- I also tried something like "If file_exists ..." and was thinking about regex.

**But I think the easiest way would be to alter the Code of that process and set "Overwrite" to false.**
Though I can't find the right file  nor did I ever write a custom function.

Can anyone help?

(The process "Export to Spreadsheet" for example has a little Checkbox that allows me to overwrite or not overwrite the existing spreadsheet)

[image: This should not be overwritten, but named like Vegetation, Vegetation-1, Vegetation-2, etc]

[image: The Model]

Comment: No, I just want to increase the suffix/numbering by 1, like: Export, Export-1, Export-2, ...